# Conformal map from the unit disk minus a segment $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ to the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was thinking about making a translation $f(z)=z-\frac{1}{2}$ first. However, it turns out to be not a "regular shape". I have no idea how to proceed then.

Comment: Use the map $z \rightarrow \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ to map it to the right half plane with $[3, \infty)$ removed, rescale $z \rightarrow \frac{z}{3}$, now map it back (using the inverse of the first map), reflect it using $z \rightarrow -z$, then positive square root it to the right half of the unit disk, then a mobuis transformation to the upper right quadrant, square it to the upper half plane and finally another mobius transform to the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you! You should make it as an answer! I think $log$ branch can be defined on $\mathbb{C}\[0,\infty)$ directly, In this case, we can directly take square root.